# QGIS 3D digitizing workflow

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I want to digitize features in QGIS from an orthophoto and set the z-value of each node from a dsm/dtm.

What is the best workflow for this?

The solution might be to simply set what layer the vector features should inherit their z-value from but as far as I have seen this is not possible?

Is there work being made in this area?